# Schedule HTTP Request on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have iOS app (written by swift) which sends user location(for emergency situation) to the server. When I get new location from device , I send it to server, if there is no internet connection maybe I lost user location, Can I schedule this request? In other words is there a service which guarantee sends this information to server when internet connection will be available? I use Geofence , I am not in background mode  , but i can get event when I entered new region

Comment: You can save the location as a property to one of your objects, and send it when the internet connection comes back

Comment: Yes i can, but there is not event when the  internet connection comes back  in background mode

Comment: But you can try to send it one time per minute until sent

Comment: @javagc if you need need also in background, then please update your question accordingly, otherwise it's an incomplete one.

Comment: Check out the plist key - “Application does not run in background”

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification when Internet became available on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733536/notification-when-internet-became-available-on-ios)

Comment: No . it is not same question . reachability does not work when user uses other app